# Laravel Cashier Re-attempt Pending Invoice after Card Updates

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-5.3, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel 5.3 with Cashier. If a customer updates their card details, how can I check if there is a pending invoice and ask Stripe to re-attempt the charge on the new card? At the moment, I have set the settings for attempts in Stripe dashboard. But from what I understand, Stripe does not automatically attempt to charge the customer if they updated their card details and it waits for the next attempt date to try again. Thats why I want to manually attempt to charge the customer on pending invoice as soon as they update their card. I read the Cashier documentation and Github page but this case is not covered there.

```
$user->updateCard($token);
// Next charge customer if there is a pending invoice
```

Can someone help me out please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing and talking with Stripe support, I found out the problem with the current `updateCard()` method used in Laravel Cashier.

With the current `updateCard()` method, the card is added to the sources list and then sets the new card as the `default_source`. the result of this method has 2 outcomes:

1. Multiple cards gets added to the list although the recent one is set as `default_source`
2. When updating the card using this method, if there are any unpaid invoices (i.e. invoices in `past_due` state), they are not automatically charged.

In order for stripe to re-attempt charging customer on all invoices in `past_due` state, the `source` parameter needs to be passed. So I have created a new method something like this:

```
public function replaceCard($token)
    {
        $customer = $this->asStripeCustomer();
        $token = StripeToken::retrieve($token, ['api_key' => $this->getStripeKey()]);
        // If the given token already has the card as their default source, we can just
        // bail out of the method now. We don't need to keep adding the same card to
        // a model's account every time we go through this particular method call.
        if ($token->card->id === $customer->default_source) {
            return;
        }
        //  Just pass `source: tok_xxx` in order for the previous default source 
        // to be deleted and any unpaid invoices to be retried
        $customer->source = $token;
        $customer->save();
        // Next we will get the default source for this model so we can update the last
        // four digits and the card brand on the record in the database. This allows
        // us to display the information on the front-end when updating the cards.
        $source = $customer->default_source
                    ? $customer->sources->retrieve($customer->default_source)
                    : null;
        $this->fillCardDetails($source);
        $this->save();
    }
```

I have created a [Pull request](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/pull/371) for this addition. Since editing the `Billable` file directly for any changes is not a good idea, if this doesnt get added to Cashier, then you can use the following in the Controller file to do it directly from there:

```
$user = Auth::User();

$customer = $user->asStripeCustomer();
$token = StripeToken::retrieve($token, ['api_key' => config('services.stripe.secret')]);

if (!($token->card->id === $customer->default_source)) {
  $customer->source = $token;
  $customer->save();
  // Next synchronise user's card details and update the database
  $user->updateCardFromStripe();
}
```

Comment: is this work with laravel 5.7  I want to charge the payment immediately once card details are updated